# htaccess redirect subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect the url `http://intranet/trac/paradox/report/6` to `http://cobra.woking/trac/paradox/report/6`. `trac` is a subfolder and `paradox` is a subfolder. `report/6` are params that need to be kept and may change.

In my apache doc root i have

```
#/opt/html/.htaccess
Redirect 301 / http://intranet/intranet
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^trac/paradox/report/6$ http://cobra.woking/trac/paradox/report/6 [L,R]
```

I have tried the following which does not work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^intranet$
RewriteRule (.*) http://cobra.woking/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^intranet$
RewriteRule (.*) http://cobra.woking/$1 [R=301,L]
```

URL i want to change is `http://intranet/trac/paradox/` to `http://cobra.woking/trac/paradox/`. I have placed `.htaccess` in the `/opt/html/trac/paradox/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file of your intranet's document root, add this to the top of the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^trac/paradox/report/6$ http://cobra.woking/trac/paradox/report/6 [L,R]
```

Comment: i have tried your change but it does not work in the log file i get `File does not exist: /opt/html/trac/paradox`